# add column as End_date with +100 days interval in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to solve this. table has `cycle and date` column, i wanna add one more column as  `end date with interval of 100 days from current date` and wanna display `cycle, start_date, end_date` as an output.

i have tried this

```
select cycle, min(start) as startt, max(start) as endd  
from cy 
group by cycle ;
```

however no luck till now.

its MYSQL DB latest version.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `cycle` INTEGER,
  `date` DATE,
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`cycle`, `date`)
VALUES
  ('1', '15-Jan-21'),
  ('2', '01-Aug-21'),
  ('3', '08-sep-21'),
  ('4', '15-Dec-21');
```

Output : [image]

Comment: Did you want to use `DATE_ADD` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72347265/add-column-as-end-date-with-100-days-interval-in-sql#72347265

Comment: @D-Shih i did `date_add('start', interval 100 day) as end_Date` however shows null values in MYSQL.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong link here is db fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc48d44a5a1adfb3a1899cbeff5fccfc

Comment: *i wanna add one more column* Do you want to add one more column into the table structure or you want to have this additional column in the output only?

Comment: @Akina obiviously in the output ( which is already shown in the output picture ), and adding new column in table which is too easy. i am looking for column in output.

Comment: What version of mysql did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you might want to use `LEAD` window function with `DATE_SUB` if your MySQL version supports that.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT *,DATE_SUB(LEAD(`date`) OVER(ORDER BY cycle), INTERVAL 1 DAY)  endDate
 FROM table1
) t1
WHERE endDate IS NOT NULL
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f062a0849abb53911383782a5298a71f)